# PHP ldap filters are not applied

Tags: php, nginx, ldap, debian

I am currently trying to restrict my LDAP Login, using LDAP filters, but for some reason, the filters have no effect. My goal is, that only Users, that are in the Group "example" can login. So the LDAP filter would be

```
(&(objectclass=user)(department=example))
```

Here is my PHP Code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

    $adServer = "ldap://ldap.domain.com";

    $ldap = ldap_connect($adServer);
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $ldaprdn = 'ad' . "\\" . $username;

    ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

    $bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $ldaprdn, $password);

    if ($bind) {
        $filter="(department=example)"; //also tried "(|(sAMAccountName=user1)(sAMAccountName=user2))";
        $result = ldap_search($ldap,"OU=example,DC=ad,DC=domain,DC=com",$filter);
        ldap_sort($ldap,$result);
        $info = ldap_get_entries($ldap,$result);
        for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++)
        {
            if($info['count'] > 1)
break;
}
@ldap_close($ldap);
session_start();
$_SESSION['sid']=session_id();
header('Location:  https://domain.example.com/success.php');
} else {
$msg = "Invalid username / password";
echo $msg;
}


}else{
?>
<html>
Form...
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

Are my LDAP filters wrong, or why aren't they applied? I also tried to allow only some users to access, but that didn't work either. Whatever filter I set, every user can login (with correct credentials ofc.).

Thanks for all answers in advance, if you need any further info/logs, please tell me

###Setup:

NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"

VERSION_ID="10"

VERSION="10 (buster)"

VERSION_CODENAME=buster

ID=debian

nginx version: nginx/1.14.2

PHP 7.3.19-1~deb10u1 (cli) (built: Jul 5 2020 06:46:45) ( NTS )

PHP 7.3.19-1~deb10u1 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Jul 5 2020 06:46:45)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are authenticating the user first (bind), before searching with the filter.
Usually, an application would search the directory for the username, and use the resulting DN to bind. That will allow you to do additional filtering such as verifying that the user also has specific attributes and values such as department example.